# Select range of cells with same value and find the middle cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have formulas in columns BHS:BWT that results a value of 1-17, these values are in groups. I would like to select the range of the smallest value and have the middle cell's value and column header resulted in column BWU of the same row. These formulas are in rows 2:51.

From picture below, in row 2, I would like to select BJP2:BJV2 (since 4 is less then 5), then return "4" and ""PRT Product 322" in BWU2.

[image: Image of Worksheet]

This can either be a formula or vba code if necessary. Thanks for any help. I do not have a starting formula as this one has me completely stumped.

Comment: It is not clear what you want!

Comment: I'm not going to do it for you, but you could use MIN to find the minimum value, then FIND to find the first and last instance (are they always consecutive?) and from there work out the middle value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the column name:
`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,CEILING((MATCH(MIN($BHS2:$BWT2),$BHS2:$BWT2) - MATCH(MIN($BHS2:$BWT2),$BHS2:$BWT2,0))/2 + MATCH(MIN($BHS2:$BWT2),$BHS2:$BWT2,0),1)))`

(if you know that the smallest group is always the first group, then this could be simplified a little)

This returns the value
`=min($BHS2:$BWT2)`

Do you actually want to return both "4" and "PRT Product 322" in BWU2?  i think it would be better to return "4" into BWU2 and "PRT Product 322" into BWV...or something like that...

Comment: When I try this formula I receive a #N/A error. The smallest group is not always first. No "4" and "PRT Product 322" do not need to both result into BWU2, they could result to BWU and BWV like you mentioned and I could just Concantenate them in a new cell.